# Long-running AEM EventListener working inconsistently - blacklisted?

Tags: osgi, aem, apache-felix

As always, AEM has brought new challenges to my life. This time, I'm experiencing an issue where an `EventListener` that listens for `ReplicationEvent`s is working *sometimes*, and normally just the first few times after the service is restarted. After that, it stops running entirely.

The first line of the listener is a log line. If it was running, it would be clear. Here's a simplified example of the listener:

```
@Component(immediate = true, metatype = false)
@Service(value = EventHandler.class)
@Property(
    name="event.topics",  value = ReplicationEvent.EVENT_TOPIC
)
public class MyActivityReplicationListener implements EventHandler {

    @Reference
    private SlingRepository repository;

    @Reference
    private OnboardingInterface onboardingService;

    @Reference
    private QueryInterface queryInterface;

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    private Session session;

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event ev) {
        log.info(String.format("Starting %s", this.getClass()));
        // Business logic
        log.info(String.format("Finished %s", this.getClass()));
    }
}
```

Now before you panic that I haven't included the *business logic*, see my answer below. The main point of interest is that the business logic could take a few seconds.

Answer (score 3):

While crawling through the second page of Google search to find an answer, I came across [this article](http://www.t-systems-mms.com/unternehmen/newsroom/detail/best-practices-newsletter-nr-2-event-handler.html). A German article explaining that `EventListeners` that take more than 5 seconds to finish are sort of silently quarantined by AEM with no output.

It just so happens that this task might take longer than 5 seconds, as it's working off data that was originally quite small, but has grown (and this is in line with other symptoms).

I put a change in that makes the listener much more like the one in that article - that is, it uses an `EventConsumer` to asynchronously process the `ReplicationEvent` using a pub/sub model. Here's a simplified version of the new model (for AEM 6.3):

```
@Component(immediate = true, property = {
        EventConstants.EVENT_TOPIC + "=" + ReplicationEvent.EVENT_TOPIC,
        JobConsumer.PROPERTY_TOPICS + "=" + AsyncReplicationListener.JOB_TOPIC
})
public class AsyncReplicationListener implements EventHandler, JobConsumer {

    private static final String PROPERTY_EVENT = "event";
    static final String JOB_TOPIC = ReplicationEvent.EVENT_TOPIC;

    @Reference
    private JobManager jobManager;

    @Override
    public JobConsumer.JobResult process (Job job) {
        try {
            ReplicationEvent event = (ReplicationEvent)job.getProperty(PROPERTY_EVENT);

            // Slow business logic (>5 seconds)

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return JobResult.FAILED;
        }
        return JobResult.OK ;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        final Map <String, Object> payload = new HashMap<>();
        payload.put(PROPERTY_EVENT, ReplicationEvent.fromEvent(event));

        final Job addJobResult = jobManager.addJob(JOB_TOPIC , payload);
    }
}
```

You can see here that the `EventListener` passes off the `ReplicationEvent` wrapped up in a `Job`, which is then handled by the `JobConsumer`, which according to this magic article, is not subject to the *5 second rule*.

Here is some [official documentation](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-event-admin.html) on this time limit. Once I had the "5 seconds" key, I was able to a bit more information, [here](https://cqdump.wordpress.com/2017/09/24/do-not-write-to-the-repository-in-event-handling/) and [here](http://www.aembeginner.com/aem-how-to-avoid-blacklisting-event-handlers-from-apache-felix-admin/), that talk about the 5 second limit as well. The first article uses a similar method to the above, and the second article shows a way to turn off these time limits.

The time limits can be disabled entirely (or increased) in the configMgr by setting the `Timeout` property to zero in the *Apache Felix Event Admin Implementation* configuration.

Comment: A typical solution is to start a new thread that handles the event. So you can make sure you return quickly.

Comment: @ChristianSchneider thanks! Is there an advantage to that over this method? With this method you get the added functionality of job processing, like viewing open jobs in the felix console.

Comment: A couple of comments. The decision by EventAdmin to blacklist a handler should have been logged... make sure you have a working LogService installed. Second point, you shouldn't disable the timeout generally because it is a valuable feature, so the approach of handing work over to another Thread (or better, to an Executor) is correct. However it's very useful to know how to disable the timeout in case you ever need to debug into an EventHandler. If you put breakpoints into a handler, it is pretty much guaranteed to timeout!

Comment: A job is indeed a good way to make sure your eventhandler returns quickly. It is an AEM specific solution though and more heavy weight than events.

Comment: @ChristianSchneider I still would go for a Sling job since they are persisted. If AEM shuts down for whatever reason long running threads are gone as well. Jobs will be there after AEM reboots etc. But obviously, that is not 100% guaranteed as well since AEM could go belly up when the job is created itself ... It is just a little bit more "robust" than simple threads.

Comment: I would use an Executor for this. It's standard Java, so reduces coupling to AEM. But is safer and more lightweight than starting a Thread, because an executor can use a single thread (or pool of threads) to execute many runnables.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback everyone! This is much more clear to me now.